# Problemas con Pivot y Join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal? Todos los errores que marcan me dicen lo mismo

> Expecting '(', or SELECT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
( select distinct


--periodo
empleados.idempleado ,
conceptos.descripcion descripcion,
valconceptos.valor,
per.numeroperiodo ,
tper.nombretipoperiodo Periodicidad_de_Pago,
per.fechainicio,
per.fechafin  
,
-- empresa
empresa.nombrecorto,
--registro patronal
regPatron.cregistroimss ,
--empleados

-- cliente - falta cliente

--personales de empleado
empleados.numerosegurosocial, 
empleados.rfc,
empleados.curpf,
empleados.codigoempleado,
empleados.apellidopaterno,
empleados.apellidomaterno,
empleados.nombrelargo,
empleados.fechaalta,
empleados.fechabaja,
-- valor nom10017
nom07.valor valornom10017,
-- saldo empleados
empleados.sueldodiario,
empleados.sueldovariable,
empleados.sueldointegrado,
-- falta neto
empleados.ajustealneto,
-- sueldos
modsueldos.sueldo,
-- septimo
per.septimos
-- TABLAS Y JOINS
from nom10001 empleados
join NOM10003 departamentos 
on empleados.iddepartamento = departamentos.iddepartamento
--incapacidades
full join nom10018 Incapacidades 
on empleados.idempleado = Incapacidades.idempleado
-- periodo
inner join nom10023 TPer 
on empleados.idtipoperiodo = tper.idtipoperiodo
inner join nom10002 per 
on tper.ejercicio = per.ejercicio
-- empresa
cross join nom10000 empresa
-- registro patronal
inner join  nom10035 regPatron
on regPatron.cidregistropatronal = 
empleados.cidregistropatronal
-- valor nom10017
inner join nom10007 nom07
on empleados.idempleado = nom07.idempleado

full join nom10019 modsueldos 
on empleados.idempleado = modsueldos.idempleado

-- conceptos
full outer join nom10044 valconceptos
on empleados.idempleado = valconceptos.idempleado

full outer join nom10004 conceptos
on conceptos.idconcepto = valconceptos.idconcepto

where per.mes = month(getdate()) 



--termina parentisis de -- select --
)
pivot(
sum(conceptos.descripcion) for [numeroperiodo] in ([1% Educación empresa],[2% Fondo retiro SAR (8)]) 
)as P
```

Comment: ¿Así no funciona?: `SELECT *  FROM ( select distinct empleados.idempleado ,  ... ) as T pivot(
sum(conceptos.descripcion) for [numeroperiodo] in ([1% Educación empresa],[2% Fondo retiro SAR (8)]) 
)as P`

Comment: genial quedó increible , pudes dejar una respuesta si quieres :3

Comment: Me alegro de que haya funcionado, ya tienes la respuesta de Cristian. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al paréntesis donde termina tu tabla derivada le falta un alias:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( select distinct empleados.idempleado , ... ) -- Acá falto el alias
pivot(...) as P

-- Así debería quedar

SELECT * 
FROM ( select distinct empleados.idempleado , ... ) T
pivot(...) as P
```